# vb.net Image Manipulation

Tags: vb.net, image

I was tasked today after creating a program to Add watermarks to also create one to remove that same watermark.

My thoughts are that it is now part of the image and can't be removed so easily.

Is this accurate or is the actually a way? ( that doesnt take 10 years)

thanks for any hints

> Here is my code to add the watermarks:

```
    Dim watermark_bm As Bitmap = Global.AnchorAuditor.My.Resources.Logo_White
    Dim watermark_bm2 As Bitmap = Global.AnchorAuditor.My.Resources.CLS_Logo_White_Engineering

    'watermark_bm2.MakeTransparent()

    ' WATERMARK IMAGE 1 - AA
    Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(s)

        Dim or_bm As Bitmap = Image.FromStream(str)

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''START IMAGE 1''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        or_bm.SetResolution(20, 20)

        Dim x1 As Integer = or_bm.Width - 300
        Dim Y As Integer = or_bm.Height - 300

        Const ALPHA As Byte = 128
        ' Set the watermark's pixels' Alpha components.
        Dim clr As Color
        For py As Integer = 0 To watermark_bm.Height - 1
            For px As Integer = 0 To watermark_bm.Width - 1
                clr = watermark_bm.GetPixel(px, py)
                watermark_bm.SetPixel(px, py, _
                    Color.FromArgb(ALPHA, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B))
            Next px
        Next py

        ' Set the watermark's transparent color.
        watermark_bm.MakeTransparent(watermark_bm.GetPixel(0, _
            0))

        ' Copy onto the result image.
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(or_bm)
        gr.DrawImage(watermark_bm, x1, Y)

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''END IMAGE 1 START IMAGE 2''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        or_bm.SetResolution(60, 60)

        Dim x2 As Integer = 75
        Dim Y1 As Integer = 75

        Const ALPHA1 As Byte = 128
        ' Set the watermark's pixels' Alpha components.
        Dim clr1 As Color
        For py As Integer = 0 To watermark_bm2.Height - 1
            For px As Integer = 0 To watermark_bm2.Width - 1
                clr1 = watermark_bm2.GetPixel(px, py)
                watermark_bm2.SetPixel(px, py, _
                    Color.FromArgb(ALPHA1, clr1.R, clr1.G, clr1.B))
            Next px
        Next py

        ' Set the watermark's transparent color.
        watermark_bm2.MakeTransparent(watermark_bm2.GetPixel(0, _
            0))

        ' Copy onto the result image.
        Dim gr1 As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(or_bm)
        gr1.DrawImage(watermark_bm2, x2, Y1)


        ''''''''''''''''''''''''END IMAGE 2'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        or_bm.Save(s & "deleteme.jpg", _
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    End Using
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct - adding a watermark is far easier than removing it.  The standard approach is to keep a copy of the original someplace and use that instead of trying to manipulate the image afterwards.